# Dimension of space of linear transformations commuting with some matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $0$ and $V$ an $n$-dimensional $F$-vector space. Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be an invertible $F$-linear map such that $T^{-1}=T$. Let
$$
W:=\{\text{linear transformations }S:V\rightarrow V~|~ST=TS\}.
$$
I would like to give a formula for $\dim W$ in terms of $n$ and $\operatorname{Trace}(T)$.

This is a qualifying exam problem I am studying for, and it feels like it should be quite doable. However, I am failing to see the trick here.

I've done some dummy computations with $2\times 2$ matrices. My suspicion is that the formula is along the lines of $\dim(W)= n^2-n+\operatorname{Trace}(T)$, but something still feels wrong.

Update on attempt:

As Greg Martin commented below, we can consider the cases depending on which eigenvalues we got. If the eigenvalue 1 appears with multiplicity $n$, then a change of basis can be made so that we can assume $T=I$ is the identity matrix. In this case, $\dim W=n^2$. Similarly, if the eigenvalue $-1$ appears with mutiplicity $n$, then $\dim W=n^2$.

This does not match up with $\dim(W)=n^2-n+\operatorname{Trace}(T)$ in both situations.

Now for the actual attempt. Let $T=\begin{pmatrix} 
I_m \\ 
& -I_l
\end{pmatrix}$
where $I_m$ denotes the $m\times m$ identity matrix. Let $S=\begin{pmatrix}S_{11} & S_{12} \\ S_{21} & S_{22} \end{pmatrix}$ and the condition $ST=TS$ is forces $S_{12}$ and $S_{21}$ to be zero. No conditions are imposed on $S_{11}$ and $S_{22}$.

In this case, the size of the blocks $S_{11}$ and $S_{22}$ are determined by $\operatorname{Trace}(T)$. In particular, the $m\times m$ matrix of $S_{11}$ has $m=\operatorname{Trace}(T)+l$ if $\operatorname{Trace}(T)>0$.

So the dimension of possible choices of $S$ is $(\operatorname{Trace}(T)+l)^2+l^2$ assuming WLOG that $\operatorname{Trace}(T)\geq 0$.

Writing this out, we get $\operatorname{Trace}(T)^2+2\operatorname{Trace}(T)l+2l^2$. But we know that
$$
\operatorname{Trace}(T)+ 2l =n
$$
so we can rewrite the this as
$$
\operatorname{Trace}(T)^2+\operatorname{Trace}(T)l+2nl.
$$

*At this point I don't know how to write this equation purely in terms of $n$ and $\operatorname{Trace}(T)$.*

Comment: Sorry, but $\det(W)$ doesn't make sense here, as $W$ is a set. What did you mean by that?

Comment: @Chickenmancer My apologies, I meant $\dim(W)$. I edited accordingly.

Comment: The fact that $T^2-I=0$ implies that $T$ is diagonalizable (with $1$ and $-1$ the only possible eigenvalues); I imagine that we're supposed to switch to a basis in which $T$ is diagonal and then do the computation by hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've computed, the dimension is $m^2 + \ell^2$. We have $\text{tr}(T) = m - \ell$ and $n = m + \ell$ so

$$m^2 + \ell^2 = \frac{(m - \ell)^2 + (m + \ell)^2}{2} = \boxed{ \frac{n^2 + \text{tr}(T)^2}{2} }.$$

Alternately we have $m = \frac{n + \text{tr}(T)}{2}$ and $\ell = \frac{n - \text{tr}(T)}{2}$ and we can substitute these in.

This calculation can be understood in the general context of the [representation theory of finite groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_finite_groups); in this case the finite group is $C_2$. The general fact is that over a field of characteristic $0$ a representation is determined up to isomorphism by its [character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_theory), and for a representation of $C_2$ the character is two numbers, the dimension and the trace of the action of $-1$, which here is $T$. Then we can write down a formula for the dimension of the algebra of endomorphisms of a representation in terms of its [irreducible decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_representation), which this $m^2 + \ell^2$ formula is a special case of.